# IBM Cloud: How to create a new resource instance via the Resource Controller API?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud

I´m trying to use the [IBM Cloud Resource Controller API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/resource-controller/resource-controller#create-resource-instance) to create a new resource instance.

I´m able to create an Access Token but I don´t know how to get all the right Query Parameters. So my problem is to find out where I can get the right **resource_plan_id** and the **resource_group**. It´s written that it is a unique ID that is provided by the Global Catalog.

Where can I find the required information?

Can someone maybe give me more information on how to create a new resource instance?

Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

One way to find out the information is to use the other [IBM Cloud Platform Services APIs](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs?tab=api-docs&category=platform_services). The [Resource Manager has an API function to get the list of available resource groups](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/resource-controller/resource-manager#list-resource-groups) in your account and to create new resource groups.

You can find information about deployable offerings via the [Global Catalog API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/resource-catalog/global-catalog#introduction), but I would recommend using the IBM Cloud CLI or 3rd party offerings like https://mycatalog.mybluemix.net/ which is a wrapper around it.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, i will try it and get back to you if it resolve my problem